# Как из php вызвать функцию C#

Tags: c#, php

Как из кода php вызвать код написанный на C# (Mono) (в виде бибилиотеки или еще как нибудь)? Желательно с примером, спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего никак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](http://www.php.su/exec), или [так](http://www.php.su/functions/?shell-exec). За примерами не ко мне, я на C# не пишу. Разумеется, программа должна быть консольной.